# How to convert string variables from one class to flask-sqlalchemy database?

Tags: python, dictionary, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

so, I created this small example to illustrate my question:

I have a (Flask) application. In this example, a user can upload files that have text about a certain fruit. I extract that information and save it in a class to process further, like this:

```
class uploaded_fruits():
     def __init__(self, fruit, taste):
          self.fruit = fruit
          self.taste = taste
```

I also save the information in a sqlalchemy database, which I use to store the information for the frontend:

```
class fruits(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    fruit = db.Column(db.String(10))
    taste = db.Column(db.String(50))
    edit = LinkCol('Edit', 'edit', url_kwargs=dict(id='id'))
```

In the `uploaded_fruits(`) I store information that another function uses, and in de `fruits()` database I store information in a way that the user understands. For example, for the sweet taste of fruit I use "`SW`" in `uploaded_fruits()` and "`Sweet`" in `fruits()`, I store this conversion in a dictionary like this:

```
Taste_list = {
    "Sweet" : "SW",
    "Sour" : "SO",
    "Salty" : "SA",
    "Bitter" : "BI",
}
```

So for example, if I would have:

```
apple = uploaded_fruits("apple", "SW")
pear = uploaded_fruits("Pear", "SW")
```

I would like to insert this in the `fuits()` database like this:

```
class fruits(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    fruit = ["apple", "pear"]
    taste = ["Sweet", "Sweet"]
```

But I can't seem to do it right. I tried this:

```
for fruit in uploaded_fruits:
        analyzed_fruits = fruits()
        analyzed_fruits.fruit = fruit.fruit

        # When the text analyses does not conclude on a taste 
        if fruit.taste is None:
            analyzed_fruit.taste = "Taste unknown 1"
        else:
            match_taste = fruit.taste

            for key, value in Taste_list.items():
                if match_taste in value:
                    analyzed_fruit.taste = key
                else:
                    analyzed_fruit.taste = "Taste unknown 2"

         db.session.add(analyzed_file)
         db.session.commit()
```

But all I now get is `"Taste Unknown 2"`, so it seems not able to match in for some reason. Could someone help me?

Comment: There's lots im confused about here. You created two instances of `uploaded_fruits` named `apple` and `pear`, but you dont use them in your loop? You should probably do something like 
`for current_fruit in [apple, pear]:` to get what you want

Comment: @enrm Ah yes, sorry I just edited it, you're right, So what I'm doing here is filling the sqlalchemy database with the uploaded_fruits() class variables. Indeed the fruit is also in there. Only one of the variables should not be saved in the form that it is in the uploaded_fruits() class, but needs to be more elaborate as this will show in the frontend